# How to make a glossary in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model called doctor.

I want to build a glossary where the user clicks on the letter (A, B, C, or, ...), and show the matching results.

What is the best way to approach this?

Doctor Model:

```
def self.filter_by_letter(letter)
    (a..z).each do |letter|
    link_to #{letter}, doctor_path(:id => letter)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is more to do with view layouts, and not model data, I would probably put it in a helper file rather than making it a class method.

So inside `/helpers/doctors_helper.rb` something like:

```
def doctor_index
  ('A'..'Z').map do |letter| # letters must be a string for range to work
    link_to letter, doctor_path(id: letter)
  end.join(" ").html_safe
end
```